# How to simulate multiple instances of the same program communicating in C?

Tags: c

I need to write code in C that will ultimately run on an embedded system and its purpose is that multiple physical instances of these embedded systems can communicate with each other.

I want to test this first in simulation, but I am not very experienced in C. In C++ or other object oriented languages, I would just create multiple instances of the same class and let them communicate in the simulation.
How could I do that in C?

Edit: To avoid misunderstandings: I am interested in how I can start up multiple instances of the code, so that every instance then has its own data.

Comment: Simulation is not reality; How are these embedded systems are to be connected to each other if needed?

Comment: In reality they connect over a wireless transceiver, in the simulation the calls to the wireless driver are abstracted to call the callbacks directly that are in reality called by the driver.
The question is really only about how I can create different "objects" of my C code without using an object oriented language.

Comment: Communicate _how_? What interface? Apart from that, a general rule of thumb is: simulators suck, use the real hardware.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. There is a wireless driver that transmits data, which of course is not there in the simulation. In the simulation there is instead a mock that calls the corresponding callbacks directly.
Regarding the simulation, I beg to differ. When I'm developing a communication protocol, how should I ensure it works in every possible situation if not by simulating it? I surely can't test all these situations with the hardware.

Comment: If your code is reentrant and uses only arguments, never globals, you can run as many instances as you want. You can write OO code in C, just pass `this` equivalent explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

You're being very vague in how exactly the two devices are going to communicate, so I'm going to assume the microchip (or whatever) you're using has some kind of interface, that will get digital pulses and store them in some fixed address in memory. If that's the case, you can make two functions:

- `send_data(char data)`, will send the other machine data
- `receive_data()`, will get the most recently sent byte of data

Then, you can make use of the C's preprocessor:

```c
#if SIMULATION
// Code for simulated data communication
#else
// Code for real data communication
#endif

void send_data(char data) {
    #if SIMULATION
    // Code for simulated data communication
    #else
    // Code for real data communication
    #endif
}
char receive_data() {
    #if SIMULATION
    // Code for simulated data communication
    #else
    // Code for real data communication
    #endif
}
```

Then, when simulating the program, just compile with `gcc ... -D SIMULATION=1`

You could then use some sort of multithreading to start up the `main` function multiple times. This is the easiest way I can think of

Comment: I am being vague about that because I think it does not matter. I already know how they will communicate, what I am interested in is what you mentioned in your last sentence: starting up the main function (and all other "objects" that store data) multiple times. I don't know how to do that in C.

Comment: This answers "how to mock functions", which isn't what OP asked.